# Change text then change text back with button click?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

Im not sure why this piece of code wont work:

```
    public void action_Click(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            boolean b1 = false;
            if (b1 == false){
                btn1.setText("TEXT 1");
                b1=true;
            }
            if (b1 == true){
                btn1.setText("TEXT 2");
                b1=false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Everytime you call this method, b1 is set to false because it's a local variable. Use static field instead. See java basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public void action_Click(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    if (button.getText().toString().equals("TEXT 1") {
        button.setText("TEXT 2");
    } else {
        button.setText("TEXT 1");
    }
}
```